# How to get steam user CS2 inventory information in json

Tags: steam, steamworks-api

I tried to get inventory via https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561199445265994/inventory/json/730/2

But i sometimes get an error with this way (*{"success":false,"Error":"Unsupported request"}*)

As i understand cs.money use way which means get steam inventory via trade link (i checked this), but i have no idea how to do it.